# gtk.treeview resizing of columns without showing headers

Tags: treeview, gtk, pygtk

Is it possible to resize gtk.TreeView columns when headers are not visible e.g. by dragging gridlines?
In my situation headers take too much space and I don't want to display them but I want columns to be resizable.

Comment: And the code is...?